# Connecting with Blob Container in one specific notebook in DataBricks

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I work under one cluster in DataBricks which has mounted blob container. I'd like to keep that one container for the whole cluster, but mount another already created cluster for one specific notebook (or repo, that would be awesome) to load data from there. How can I make it?

Example:

Repo 1 - blob 1:

- notebooks blob 1
  Repo 2 - blob 1 (or blob if its possible)
- notebook (notebooks) blob2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following procedure load the data into storage account.

I reproduce same in my environment with two repro's

**Repro 1:**

*Container name: `input` Mount_point:`/mnt/hffj`*

[image]

**Repro 2:**

*Container name: `output` Mount_point:`/mnt/output`*

[image]

**As per above scenario you can do in this way:**

*First of all read the data frame*

```
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/mnt/hffj")
```

*Then, write it into repro 2 mount path `/mnt/output`. Data is stored in that mount location*

```
df1.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/output")
```

[image]

Comment: By ```repro``` you mean code repository right? Using this, one repository will get data from ```input``` blob and second from ```output```? Both repositories are attached to the same workspace cluster? Sorry, but I want to make sure before I start messing with it.

Comment: Yes, repro means code repository. Both repositories are attached to different cluster

Comment: What if I have one cluster attached to the workspace?

Comment: nothing will happen it works perfectly fine with one cluster also. you can check this repository [link1](https://i.imgur.com/qg1GVS3.png) and [link2](https://i.imgur.com/JD5jMDu.png)